# Getting 5 beeps plus another 5 beeps on a ThinkPad T440p

Tags: laptop, bios, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, post

So, I am trying to repair a ThinkPad T440p for a family member, and I am getting the 5 beeps of death. It is a T440p with an i5 and Nvidia Graphics.

Basically, when I press the power button, it beeps 5 times, pauses, then beep another 5 times. I heard this could be a TPM issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems unlikely to be a TPM issue. Get the Lenovo Diagnostics App on a bootable USB key. Put the USB key, try to start and see if you can check hardware. If not, get it serviced.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Do you have a link for that software? Also, another idea I had was trying to re-flash the BIOS. What keys do I press to get it to go into BIOS recovery mode? I want to avoid having to pay to get it serviced, as it is an old laptop. I am pretty good with computers, but this issue really has me stuck.

Comment: Go to Lenovo support, enter your model and look for diagnostics.   BIOS will be there as well. Try both.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will let you know if it works!

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/aths30/5_beeps_pause_5_beeps/ . The POST beeps indicate a motherboard issue, **but** "reset BIOS by removing the CMOS battery and holding the power button for 30 seconds, then letting the battery charge up." Also, try changing CMOS cell and removing and re-seat RAM.

Comment: I tried those things, but the problem is, whenever I plug the laptop in, it turns on automatically. I turned it off, and let it charge, but it didn’t work. I also tried the RAM reseat, but I had no luck. I even tried a totally different RAM stick from a known working machine. Still, no luck.